# How do I determine a page's content type for non-node pages?

Tags: theming

I’m trying to modify my theme’s `page.tpl.php` to not show certain regions when I’m displaying content from the core forum module.

```
<?php if (!$node->type == 'forum'): ?>
<div id="sidebar"><?php print $sidebar; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine when I display actual forum nodes, but not when I show pages with the forum listings (/forum, /forum/1, etc.), since those pages aren't actually nodes.

How can I determine if a *page* will be a certain content type, so I can use conditional statements in `page.tpl.php`?

**Edit:** Some quick clarification. Working with `$node->type` is easy for pages that actually use nodes. However, when working with Views, or in the case of the forum module, the content is *not* node-based (it is called with `forum-topic-list.tpl.php` and `$node` is null). Because of this, it's impossible to programmatically determine if the page is really a forum (since it's not really a node). I'm trying to figure out a way around that.

**Edit 2:** Possible (kludgy?) solution: Putting this in `theme_preprocess_page` works. Is it the best way to do it though?

```
// Determine if page is a forum
$node = $vars['node'];
$template = $vars['template_files'][0];

if ($template == 'page-forum' || $node->type == 'forum') {
    $vars['is_forum'] = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [template_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/6) for detecting node on page and pass additional variable as flag to template file, like:

```
$variables['display_region'] = TRUE;
```

Maybe Panels can help you too.

Comment: That doesn't quite solve the problem. Not all pages are nodes, especially when working with views or the forum module. Pages that display the forum details call `forum-topic-list.tpl.php` and don't act as nodes—$node-type is null on those pages.

Answer (score 0):

Pages do not have a content type, only nodes do. You're trying to do something programmatically here that is actually very easy to accomplish via the Drupal UI.

I would suggest that instead of hiding the sidebar region on non-forum pages in the page template, simply set the sidebar blocks' visibility to be shown only on forum pages:

```
forum
forum/*
```

Then you only need a simple check to see if there is sidebar content in your page template

`if($sidebar):`

More information on Block Visibility settings here: http://drupal.org/node/21870